# Using ReactiveUI InvokeCommand Extension with Changing Targets

Tags: c#, reactiveui

While the below code works, I'm not sure it is the best practice.  I'm wondering if I am over-thinking the situation.

Situation: The below code is in my main ViewModel constructor.  The ViewModel has a property `MessageHandler` that has a `ReactiveCommand` property on it called `ReceiveMessage`.  The ViewModel has another property `ScannerViewModel` with a `RawMessage` Property on it.  I would like to use the ReactiveUI `.InvokeCommand()` extension method to pipe `RawMessage` to `ReceiveMessage`.  I want this due to the convenience of it checking the `.CanExecute` for me.  This should happen even though `MessageHandler` (or even `ReceiveMessage` potentially) could change, as well as `ScannerViewModel`.

```
 this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.MessageHandler.ReceiveMessage)
     .Select(cmd => 
             this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ScannerViewModel.RawMessage)
                 .InvokeCommand(cmd))
     .Scan(Disposable.Empty,
             (acc, n) =>
                        {
                            acc.Dispose();
                            return n;
                        })
     .Subscribe();
```

So the above seems to work.  I'm not too sure about whether or not I need to dispose the previous `InvokeCommand` disposables as I go along, so maybe the `.Scan` section is unneeded, or perhaps could be done better.

I tried the overload of the `InvokeCommand` extension that lets you assign a target but it seemed to be static, or I could not figure out the syntax to make it take an `Observable` as a target:

```
 this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ScannerViewModel.RawMessage)
     .InvokeCommand(MessageHandler, m => m.ReceiveMessage);
```

That would follow the `RawMessage` as its parent changed, but breaks if `MessageHandler` changed.  And this does not compile:

```
 this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ScannerViewModel.RawMessage)
     .InvokeCommand(this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.MessageHandler), m => m.ReceiveMessage);
```

I'm not against keeping what I've got, unless someone finds a flaw with it.  I am looking for something that is maybe a little less verbose and easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask me why I didn't think to just do this:

```
 this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ScannerViewModel.RawMessage)
     .InvokeCommand(this, t => t.MessageHandler.ReceiveMessage);
```

I was looking at it upside down.  I think this will achieve what I want.

Time and again I keep finding this framework has already found solutions to problems I find -- it is just a matter of grokking it for myself.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us :) It's 2021 and I'm new to Reactive UI, thanks for sharing your solution. The amazing library has got everything covered!